# How to set DB_Database field in .env from controller at runtime in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to set DB_Database field in .env file according to need at runtime just to switch from one database to other. How to set it from controller ?? is there any way to set .env fields??

Comment: you can specify database.$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);

Comment: Provide some code so we can help you! Database choice you setup in `model` or when you run query `DB::connection(connection_name')` where`connection_name` is defined in .env

Comment: This can help you: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/change-database-name-of-connection-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible but it is not good idea. For switch between DB you can:

1.Add connection to your `config/database.php` file:

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

],
```

2.Specify connection for DB request:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql')->select(...);
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```